# PHP doesn't recognize POST from Android HttpsURLConnection

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send a login POST request to my PHP/MySQL backend from an Android app, and for some reason, my PHP app is not seeing the POST request from Android. I've checked in the Network Profiler section of Android Studio, and I can see that it is sending a POST request, but each time I send the request, the app receives the "Request method incorrect." JSON response I have setup.

I have tried every iteration of every possible solution I can think of to get this to work, and I have no idea what I'm missing. I will post both the Android code and the PHP code so that somebody somewhere can hopefully point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong here.

I have created a very simple web form on my server to test the login data, and it can see POST requests just fine from another PHP script. The problem comes, however, when Android tries to POST to the script - for some reason the app doesn't recognize what Android is sending as a POST request.

This is my entire "doInBackground" activity of the Async portion of my Android app.

```java
String action = params[0];

        if (action.equals("login")) {
            // Url to login at
            String postUrl = Urls.URL_LOGIN;

            // Username and password from login form
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(postUrl);
                boolean redirect = false;

                do {
                    redirect = false;

                    String urlParameters = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    int postDataLength = postData.length;

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(20000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);

                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter osW = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osW);

                    writer.write(urlParameters);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();

                    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1"));

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String json;

                        while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(json + "\n");
                        }

                        bufferedReader.close();
                        inputStream.close();

                        conn.disconnect();

                        return sb.toString().trim();
                    } else {
                        redirect = true;
                        Log.d("*** RANDOM CHAT ***", "HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);

                        return null;
                    }
                } while (redirect);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
```

And this is my entire PHP app listening for POSTs.

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once("inc.db.php");
require_once("inc.fx.php");

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "login") {
        if(is_valid(array('username','password'))) {
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $password = md5($_POST["password"]);

            if(count_db("users",array("username","password","banned"),array($username,$password,0))["data"] > 0) {
                $response = get_db("users",array("username","password"),array($username,$password));
            } else {
                $response["success"] = false;
                $response["data"] = "Invalid login information. Username: " . $username . ", Password: " . $password;
            }
        } else {
            $response["success"] = false;
            $response["data"] = "Username and password required for login. Username: " . $_POST["username"] .", Password: " . $_POST["password"];
        }
    } elseif(isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "register") {
        if(is_valid(array('username','password'))) {
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $password = md5($_POST["password"]);

            if((count_db("users",array("username"),array($username))["data"] <= 0) && (count_db("users",array("email"),array($email))["data"] <= 0)) {
                if(insert_db("users",array("username","email","password"),array($username,$email,$password))) {
                    $response = get_db("users",array("username"),array($username));
                } else {
                    $response['success'] = false;
                    $response['data'] = "Unable to create user.";
                }
            } else {
                $response["success"] = false;
                $response["data"] = "Username or email exists.";
            }
        } else {
            $response["success"] = false;
            $response["data"] = "Username, email, and password required for registration.";
        }
    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['data'] = "No server action specified.";
    }
} else {
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['data'] = "Request method incorrect.";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

I would expect that the very basic server REQUEST_METHOD check would pass since I am sending a POST, however it isn't. Once that check passes, I'm assuming the PHP code would have no problems reading the username and password of the POST request and sending the valid response back to the app for me to handle later.

And just in case anyone would like to see it, here is the Network Profiler information when attempting to login from the app:

[image: Android Network Profiler]

Comment: If your server REQUEST_METHOD is failing, then what is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` equal to? What response is coming back?

Comment: On line 9 of the PHP script, I am using ```if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){``` so I'm checking to see if the request is a POST request from the Android app. Android shows it is sending a POST request, but PHP isn't interpreting it as such for whatever reason. It's like the PHP script just completely wigs out and doesn't notice a POST is hitting it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I finally fixed the issue. I have an .htaccess file at the root of my website (this Android app is hitting a subdomain). That .htaccess file was redirecting ALL traffic to the https://www portion of my website, which for some reason, was catching my subdomain as well.

I found this by looking at the apache logs on my server for the subdomain, and noticing that the response was 301, so I knew something was wrong and being redirected somewhere. After disabling the .htaccess redirects, I finally received a response back in the app that I was looking for.

Sorry for the trouble, and hopefully this can help someone else out!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `POST` method for passing login credentials at `android` side. While at php side you first check whether it's a `POST` request and then try to get parameters with a `GET` request.

Use this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
}
```

Comment: Well, the "action" is actually a parameter I pass in the URL itself to let the api script know that I am logging in. I have another section in the api.php script for "register", so the URL I am POSTing data to is "api.php?action=login".

Comment: Thank you for trying, however that still didn't help. I went ahead and changed my script in the PHP application to check for an "action" POST variable, and in the app itself I changed the URL to just call "api.php" instead of "api.php?action=login". It still isn't working, though.

I even went into the api.php script and did:

```php
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
 $response["message"] = $key . ": " . $val;
}
```

At the very beginning of the file, before any request_method is called, just to catch any $_POST variables, and it didn't print anything in the app.

Comment: I appreciate you attempting to help, but it didn't resolve the issue, even after I made the changes. I think it might be something on the Android side, like it isn't sending the right headers, or maybe my PHP side isn't listening for the right headers, or something along those lines... I have no idea.